# git pull does nothing / git push just hangs / debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

Tags: ssh, git, openssh, github

I had an issue in ubuntu 13.10 and 12.10 where attempting to connect to github (git clone / pull / push or anything) would fail with no output.

I checked my /.ssh directory for `config` and any ssh keys. Had no config file and the ssh key for `id_rsa` was the same one that was live on my github.com account.

I attempted to ping the github servers and was able too.

I followed the github guide to debug the situation - it suggests

```
ssh -T -v git@github.com
```

The output stops at:

```
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

Anyone have a solution to allow my git pull / push etc to work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution was found here: [SSH works in putty but not terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/568891/ssh-works-in-putty-but-not-terminal)

in Ubuntu 13.10/12.10, login and gain sudo access.

Edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, uncomment the following lines

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
```

Add the following line

```
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

You should end up with your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file looking like this

```
Host *
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

Now run `ssh -T -v git@github.com` and it will ask you to add the server to your known hosts file. Hit yes, and then it should welcome you to the server.

```
Hi ****! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: Old question but: can you tell me why the problem emerges and how the addition of these lines resolves it?

Comment: Linked answer explains it

Answer (score 7):

Change the network interface MTU to solve it. This is a bug for ubuntu 14.04.

This worked for me:

```
sudo ip li set mtu 1200 dev wlan0
```

[ssh fails to connect to VPN host - hangs at 'expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY'](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1254085/comments/9)

Comment: for arch that’s `sudo ip li set mtu 1200 dev vpn0`

Comment: It fixed the issue for me but why was it an issue in the first place? What does it do?