# GitHub SSH connection hangs

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, wireless-router, git, github

macOS Sierra 10.12.5. SSH keys are set up correctly. `ssh -T -vvv git@github.com` shows that I cannot connect to GitHub via SSH at all:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.30.253.112 port 22: Operation timed out
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.30.253.113 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

I have tried a couple of suggestions for similar problems (e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/699530/git-pull-does-nothing-git-push-just-hangs-debug1-expecting-ssh2-msg-kex-ecd)) but none worked for me. I suspect it's a network issue with my new wireless router. Anyone has seen similar problems before?

Comment: I see the DNS response but then with each attempt to connect it is timing out.  You don't have a single successful port 22 connection, so I believe you are correct about the networking.  Does this happen with other ssh connections, like to your website service provider?

Comment: I can SSH into my company machines, but that's through a VPN connection.

Comment: OK. `ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com` was successful, so it looks like port 22 is blocked. But I don't know why? I have turned off the firewall in the admin page. P.S. ISP is RCN, modem/router is Ubee UBC1301.

Comment: That's interesting.  Sounds like a firewall issue at first, but if you unblocked the port there then we're with a head-scratcher.  Hmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you solved this, but I am convinced there is buggy firmware in the Ubee UBC1301 on RCN's 1 Gig service which for whatever reason is blocking outbound port 22.  I've made a post about it here (I noticed your post)

https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r31446148-Connectivity-SSH-Issues-Connection-Timeouts-with-RCN-1-Gigabit

There are several possible solutions that you may want to try if you are still having this issue.

1. Put the Ubee into Bridge Mode, which should let it pass through all of its data, you'll need your own router, since it disables the routing functions of it. Ensure you hook up to Port 1. (I personally had issues with this, since it never resolved an IP)
2. Change the Firewall settings on the modem.  Lowering or turning the Firewall on the Ubee. (I never got this to work)
3. See if you can request a equipment swap to get a modem only without the gateway functions, or downgrade service.

You could also just continue using the VPN, but I would think you lose the benefits of the speeds of having 1 gig.

I ended up downgrading service, and getting back an older modem, which worked perfectly, and was able to SSH normally.

Comment: Thanks for the response @kev5873. I ended up using port 443 for all my outbound SSH connections. I tried 2 and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Also experienced this issue, also with an Ubee UBC1301 (UBC1301AA00), hardware version 3.37.2 software version 12.2.3101.20. The key setting turned out to be LAN>DHCPv4>LAN firewall; turning that off fixed it. (Even though I was connected via wifi.)